# Karate -Gatling: Not able to update simulation class name

Tags: karate

I am doing one POC with Karate gatling to know the feasibility of this combination for our performance requirement. As of now, I am able to successfully run karate feature files with gatling.

But I am facing two issues:

1. I am not able to update the simulation class name. 
   The demo(karate gatling) project simulation default class name is CatsKarateSimulation. I want to rename it.

**Issue is:**

When I rename it, it starts throwing this error:

Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:test (default-cli) on project karate-gatling-demo: Gatling failed.: No simulations to run

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

When I change the class name same as CatsKarateSimulation, it works as expected.

2. The second problem is, I would like to know, that, for a particular API, If I want to run two performance scenario, like below:

setUp

(
    create.inject(**rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)**).protocols(protocol),
    create.inject(**atOnceUsers**(50).protocols(protocol)
   )

How can I do it? Do I need to create two simulation classes or do I need to give two different names for the same feature file(below)?

setUp(
    createWithRampUsers.inject(rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    createAtOnceUsers.inject(atOnceUsers(50).protocols(protocol)
  )

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to use your IDE refactoring support - just like Java, you need to change the class name also within the file and you should be good.

```
class DeepaksSimulation extends Simulation
```

2) I really don't know the answer :) Can you try all the options and report back please so that it helps others. But I think giving two names to the same feature would be the safest.